# Remove all numbers from .txt file in a def function-Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Input:** I want to take a .txt file filed with content(see example content that will be in a .txt file below)

> `soccerfif@yahoo.com 366-44-4444 Jezos was born Jeffrey Preston Jorgensen on January 12, 1964, also 5 and 4`

**Process:** I want to run it through my Def function (replace_numbers)

**Output:** I want the file that was ran through the function to be appended to remove all numbers (see example below)

> `soccerfif@yahoo.com 366-44-4444 Jezos was born Jeffrey Preston Jorgensen on January 12, 1964, also  and`

Here is my code:

```
import re
theFile=open("/home/file/wow.txt",'rt', encoding= 'latin-1').read()
words=theFile.split()
def replace_numbers(words):
    new_words=[]
    for word in words:
        pattern= re.compile(" \d+")
        if pattern.match(1):
            new_word= re.sub(pattern, " ", word)
            new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words

r=replace_numbers(words)
print(r)
```

Ran I ran this code i got an error of: expected string or bytes-like object

Any suggestions on how to use a def function to do this with a file.?

Comment: Can you post the exact Traceback message ?

Comment: *Where* did the error message indicate the problem was?  And your sample expected output doesn't have anything appended at all.

Comment: Even 12 and 1964 are numbers. I saw you haven't removed them in your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would go about it :

```
theFile = open ("wow.txt",'rt', encoding= 'latin-1').read()
words = theFile.split()

def replace_numbers (words) :
    exclude_list = [str (x) for x in range (10)]
    new_words = []
    for word in words :
        if word not in exclude_list :
            new_words.append (word)
    return new_words

r = replace_numbers (words)
print (r)
```

Comment: `exclude_list = list('0123456789')` would be a lot more readable. And from quick testing, it's 1000 times faster.